# Difference between service role and service role for an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html . I don't understand what the docs are trying to convey.

When you see the first line in the section **service role for an EC2 instance** , It says the "It is a special type of service role that a service assumes to launch an Amazon EC2 instance that runs your application." Later it says "This role is assigned to the EC2 instance when it is launched". Which doesn't make any sense (self-contradicting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked a very interesting question.

First, move your comment about EC2 instance into your question. This will make your question better and clearer on what you are asking.

The difference between "AWS Service Role for an EC2 instance" and "AWS Service Role" is in the sentence:

"AWS automatically provides temporary security credentials that are attached to the role and then makes them available for the EC2 instance to use on behalf of its applications."

EC2 gets one set of credentials based upon your IAM User permissions to create and launch the EC2 instance. You can then assign a different set of permissions (temporary security credentials from an IAM Role) that the applications on the EC2 instance can use.

There are other AWS services that this description would fall into. Lambda, ECS, etc. I think that this specific topic is legacy from the days when EC2, S3, DynamoDB were the major services. Today, the service offering is vast.

Think of it like this: When you are building your new house, you need one set of permissions for the construction. Later when you move into the house you need a different set of permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, When can an EC2 assumes a role that makes it launch another EC2 instance, what does that mean by this "**EC2 gets one set of credentials based upon your IAM User permissions to create and launch the EC2 instance**"

Comment: Let's say the administrator for the AWS creates a user account Bob. He can create the account Bob without the ability to launch a new EC2 instance but with the ability to start one. These permissions are the first one that I spoke about. After the EC2 instance starts, a second set of permissions can be assigned to the instance. This is the temporary credentials that I mentioned. These credentials are used by the software running inside the instance. You could limit these credentials to only read S3 objects for example.

Comment: You completely right about how the apps on EC2 get the temp credentials, My question was if there is a typo here as this role for EC2 instance to provide the app running on it to get the access to other services. But the first lines  in the section ** service role for an EC2 instance ** (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html) say something which is not right. (see next comment)
Is that a typo in AWS docs.

Comment: #It says the "It is a special type of service role that a service assumes to launch an Amazon EC2 instance that runs your application." Later it says "This role is assigned to the EC2 instance when it is launched".

Comment: If your goal is to nit-pick AWS documentation, then open a support case with AWS and help them improve it.

Comment: Thanks John. I was so nit-picking that because I'm worried if I'm missing any real info in those lines. So I was hoping if someone could help me not misled with that.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and help John.

Comment: You are welcome. One of the many things that I love about AWS: A vast number of features with very good documentation that solve real world problems.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html

As Mentioned:A set of permissions that grant access to actions and resources in AWS. These permissions are attached to the role, not to an IAM user or group.
These Permission are used to grant or revoke the Access of services used into the AWS Server.

According to this document link.
**AWS service role:** This Like Admin role By which we configure what other user can do or assign permission to them.
**AWS service role for an EC2 instance** EC2 is instance of application. Tis role attach with instance. So by there permission assigned to that role application will able to connect to other services like S3 storage, IAM User configuration etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But when you see the first line in the section **service role for an EC2 instance** , It says the "It is a special type of service role that a service assumes to launch an Amazon EC2 instance that runs your application." Later it says "This role is assigned to the EC2 instance when it is launched". Which doesn't make any sense (self-contradicting)